# C# What alternative ways are there to propagate an Event down a call chain?

Tags: c#, events, chaining

Imagine that `Main.c`s calls `sub.cs` which calls `action.cs`. `action.cs` raises and event which `sub.cs` subscribes to, however, `sub.cs` does not care about the event it is only `main.cs` that wants to know about this so `sub.cs` raises the event again so that `main.cs` can subscribe to it and discover that `action.cs` has raised the original event; which seems so cumbersome.

**What alternatives are there to passing events on through a chain of method calls?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a callback instead of events.
You can add a callback function as additional parameter to the methods of method chain.
E.g. if the method is `doSomething()` replace it with `doSomething(Action action)` and Main.c calls this method with `Sub.doSomething(() => ReactToTheEvent());` and Action.cs calls `action();` insetad of raising the event.

Answer (score 3):

You can directly attach event exposed in `Sub` at event exposed in `Action`, of course event need to be exposed both in `Sub` and in `Action`:

```
class SubClass
{
    public event EventHandler MyEvent
    {
        add
        {
            _action.MyEvent += value;
        }
        remove
        {
            _action.MyEvent -= value;
        }
    }

    private ActionClass _action;
}
```

With this solution you still have to declare event twice but you do not chain method calls and you can omit event handler in `SubClass`.

There are alternatives, of course, but you may need to change your design and I don't have enough context to suggest anything. In general I'd start with simplest possible solution. If you need just to *bubble* one event this may be enough but if you need to expose many of them then you may consider to introduce a third object which exposes what you need and make accessible through `SubClass` from `ActionClass`, something like this (but please with  better names):

```
public sealed class Notifications
{
    public event EventHandler MyEvent;

    internal void RaiseMyEvent(EventArgs e)
    {
        var myEvent = MyEvent;
        if (myEvent != null)
            myEvent(this, e);
    }
}

class MyAction
{
    public Notifications Notifications
    {
        get { return _notifications; }
    }

    // ...
}

class SubClass
{
    public Notifications Notifications
    {
        get { return _action.Notifications; }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Note that this example is just a proof of concept.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use pub-sub with topics, for instance see https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-dotnet.html

(You don't need rabbitmq for that you can implement simple pub-sub yourself or take one from github/MSDN see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752254(v=vs.110).aspx, https://github.com/upta/pubsub/blob/master/README.md)